SpringSecurity, disable security when using a specific profile in maven
I am facing this problem, I want to disable SpringSecurity when I am using the "dev" profile in maven, and have it working wen using the "prod" profile.
Initially I used a very basic version of SpringSecurity that was pretty out-of-the-box, in that case I just used this property inside application.properties file:
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration

that was working fine, the problem came when I added a custom @Configuration class like this:
@Configuration

public class SecurityConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(s->s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager))
            .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .headers(h -> h.cacheControl(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    
        return http.build();
    }

}

I then have this error and the program crashes.
Parameter 0 of method authenticationManager in it.kevinpirola.passacarte.security.SecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration' that could not be found.

My goal is to disable security when I am developing, just not to have the hassle of inputting the password each time, the second thing I would like to keep that in the profile specific application.properties as not to have code specific to this particular case used just to solve an infrastructural problem.
Anyone has an idea?

If you were defining the profile(s) using spring.profiles.active, you could annotate the configuration class with
@Profile("!dev")

Since your goal is to disable the bean based on Maven profile, you could provide its value to Spring by adding the following to your POM:
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>


You can create two different security configuration classes, one for the "dev" profile that disables security and one for the "prod" profile that enables it.
Security Configuration for Production:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // Require authentication for all requests
            .and()
            .formLogin(); // Enable form login
    }
    ...
}

Security Configuration for Development:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("dev")
public class DevSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll(); // Allow all requests without authentication
    }
    ...
}

Use Spring Profiles
Make sure to specify the active profile when running your application. You can do this by setting the spring.profiles.active property in your application.properties file:
## application.properties (dev, prod)
spring.profiles.active=dev

## application.yml (dev, prod)
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

 spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  ...
---
  spring:
    config:
      activate:
       on-profile: prod

Your application will behave differently based on the active profile, allowing you to disable Spring Security during development and enable it in production seamlessly.
